# ng test SUCCESS - should break with do not match any signature - on Linux

Tags: linux, angular, unit-testing

I just noticed something strange on a project I am currently working on. To make sure it's not linked to my project I created a new on from scratch using Angular CLI.
When **running ng test** I get the result *SUCCESS*, but **as soon as I save without any change** my spec file I get the error I was expecting :

```
ERROR in /home/.../my-app/src/app/my-component/my-component.component.spec.ts (24,16): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

Here is my version of CLI:

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.2
node: 6.10.2
os: linux x64
@angular/common: 4.1.3
@angular/compiler: 4.1.3
@angular/core: 4.1.3
@angular/forms: 4.1.3
@angular/http: 4.1.3
@angular/platform-browser: 4.1.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.1.3
@angular/router: 4.1.3
@angular/cli: 1.0.2
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.1.3
```

Here are the steps to reproduce this problem:

```
ng new my-app
cd my-app
ng g component my-component
ng g class my-class userModel
```

The UserModel looks like this :

```
export class UserModel {
  constructor(
    public name: string,
    public age: number,
    public gender: string
  ) {}
}
```

Then I just update my-component.component.spec

```
import { UserModel } from './../userModel';
.
.
.
it('should create', () => {
  let user = new UserModel('name', 42);
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

I know that I should call the UserModel with 3 parameters (VSCode is even highlighting the missing argument) and that is exactly what I want to test. I want to make sure that, if I create a new object and the signature does not match the issue is raised from the beginning.

The strange thing is that on my other computer, running on Windows, when I run **ng test** the result is a failure just as expected.

I'm not sure if this is linked to angular cli or jasmine or karma and I'm not sure that this is a real bug or something that could come from my computer.

Thanks a lot for any help!